# show Disassembly dialog box appears

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to execute my code, I'm getting an error dialog: 'Show Disassembly' which
is preventing me from executing my code. What does this problem mean and how can I solve it.

Comment: It would also help if you showed us the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mean that unhadled exceptions is thrown from your code, try to press debug and choose visual studio as the debuger, and you will see the point of exception if you have sources...